# Recyclerview click event not working with databinding and livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I'm new in Kotlin, I'm using databinding library to set items in recyclerview which I'm getting from viewmodel and calling clicklistener inside activity class. I have defined an interface in my adapter class and implemented in activity but nothing happens when I click on the recyclerview item and also not getting any error. I'm unable to figure out the mistake

My adapter looks like this

```
class NewsAdapter (private var listener: OnNewsClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
private val mCategoryList = ArrayList<Newslist>()

fun setAppList(categoryModel: ArrayList<Newslist>) {
    mCategoryList.addAll(categoryModel)
    //notifyItemRangeInserted(0, categoryModel.size)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Log.d("LIST_SIZE","" + mCategoryList.size)
    return mCategoryList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val appInfo = mCategoryList[position]
   (holder as NewsAdapter.RecyclerHolderCatIcon).bind(appInfo, listener)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val applicationBinding = ItemNewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
    return RecyclerHolderCatIcon(applicationBinding)
}

interface OnNewsClickListener {
    fun onNewsClick(position: Int)
}

inner class RecyclerHolderCatIcon(private var applicationBinding:ItemNewsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(applicationBinding.root) {
    fun bind(appInfo:Newslist, listener: OnNewsClickListener?) { 
        applicationBinding.newsItem  = appInfo
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not set listener for for item layout.
You don't need to define OnNewsClickListener interface.

```
inner class RecyclerHolderCatIcon(private var applicationBinding:ItemNewsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(applicationBinding.root) {
    fun bind(appInfo:Newslist) { 
        applicationBinding.root.setOnClickListener{ /*handle click here*/ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the click listener in `bind` like this.

Here is a sample code, you will need to modify it

```
fun bind(appInfo:Newslist, listener: OnNewsClickListener?) { 
    applicationBinding.newsItem  = appInfo
    itemView.setOnClickListener( view -> {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onNewsClick();
        }
    }
}
```